# Pushing element into an array javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I need help debugging this piece of logic in javascript, I have set hard breakpoints to check the values of my variables but I cannot push my variables back into arrays: origin and destination. The two arrays are just a collection of the joined lat longs values. I have a TSV that is a row of two points that are broken down into their lat longs respectively, I am rejoining each one into a pair and then pushing it into my origin and destination arrays.

A sample line for the output.tsv

```
Points 36.4535252345245 -122.3242534522 35.4535435435 -123.3342443545
```

Code:

```
var origins = [];
var destinations = [];

d3.tsv('output.tsv', function(data){
    var json = JSON.stringify(data);
    var i;
    for(i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
        var lat1, lat2, long1, long2;
        var point1, point2;

        lat1 = data[i].b;  //value = 36.4535252345245
        long1 = data[i].c; //value = -122.3242534522
        lat2 = data[i].d;  //value = 35.4535435435
        long2 = data[i].e; //value = -123.3342443545

        point1 = lat1 + ', ' + long1; //value = 36.4535252345245, -122.3242534522
        point2 = lat2 + ', ' + long2; //value = 35.4535435435, -123.3342443545
        origins.push(point1)   
        destinations.push(point2)
    }
})(); -> ERROR : Uncaught TypeError: d3.tsv(...) is not a function(anonymous function)
```

UPDATE:

The pushing to an array part of the problem has been solved. It was a grammar mistake.

Still getting Uncaught TypeError: d3.tsv(...) is not a function(anonymous function) & a new error InvalidValueError: not an Object

Comment: I bet it's something like `origin isn't defined`, because it isn't.

Comment: @m_callens And fixing the typo. The error is happening within the function. Whether or not the IIFE is correct or not, you still need to use variables that exist.

Comment: Why are you doing this? `d3.tsv` gives you an array of objects, each object having keys based on the first line of your TSV and values based on the other lines. If your TSV contains the correct latitudes and longitudes, you don't need all this math.

Comment: And you can't put those parenthesis at the end. `d3.tsv` is an asynchronous code that will run the moment the browser gets to it.

Comment: The end goal is to map out multiple routes on google maps, the tsv file has 20 + rows, each row has two points ( a origin and a destination) broken down into their lats and longs. Joining them together and then passing them to these arrays lets me send a collection of coordinates to the the map.

Comment: D3 does that for you! But, before anything, remove those parenthesis at the end.

Comment: Yup, those parenthesis are were left behind from an old function! Thanks @GerardoFurtado

Comment: @GerardoFurtado really? I didn't know it could plot routes, possible to link an example please

Comment: It depends on what are you doing. something like this? http://www.bytemuse.com/post/airline-routes-contiguous-united-states-d3-js/   This is also D3: http://www.tnoda.com/blog/2014-04-02

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your code. Should it be...
`origins.push(point1)` and `destinations.push(point2)`

Comment: Good catch! Fixed the push problem.